# Can I apply to another position while only spending three months in my current position?

Tags: postdocs, career-path

I got a UKRI postdoc position for two years and I currently worked only for 3 months, I want to leave this job because of the toxic lab. I found another position and I want to apply for it. Will it affect the outcome of the application? will it raise questions that I left the position early?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are still in the probation period, get out of there, apply to another position and keep the previous references you provided for the current toxic job.
You can briefly explain to your references that the lab did not live up to your expectations and you decided it was better to part way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't bound by law or contract you can apply. How it is perceived that you left another position is up to those reviewing the application.

And the funding of your current award is likely not going to be transferrable to a new position, though I don't know the rules for these.

But, you may have a ready reply to any questions asked of you.

So, it is probably better to try than not if the current position is bad enough to take the trouble.